# Shell commands to determine if file is held on an APFS volume

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, apfs

In a shell script, I need to determine if a file is held on an AFPS volume. What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1. Use a combination of `basename` (to get the full path of the file, if required) and `df` to determine which volume the file is on.
2. Use `diskutil info` to determine the filesystem type of the volume (you could also use `mount`).

There are perhaps better ways of doing it but that will certainly work.

The following one-liner was suggested by [fd0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/128657/fd0) in a comment:

```
df -T apfs /absolute/path/to/file >/dev/null && Do Stuff
```

This executes `"Do Stuff"` only if the file is on an APFS filesystem. If `Do Stuff` is more than a few simple commands the same can be accomplished with

```
if df -T apfs /absolute/path/to/file >/dev/null; then
    do stuff
    do even more stuff
fi
```