# Determine Device for a File

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

In a shell script, I need to determine the device for a file, subsequent use with diskutil, eg...

```
# ??? Assign device to FileDevice, based on full path.
diskutil info $FileDevice
```

Comment: How does this relate to [your other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384968/shell-commands-to-determine-if-file-is-held-on-an-apfs-volume)?

Comment: My functional need changed a little since that one; now it's to determine the type of volume, not just if it's APFS or not.

Comment: @nohillside Here's my combined solution: Returns file system personality for a file:


diskutil info $(df $filepath | sed -n 2p | cut -d ' ' -f 1) | grep '^   File System Personality:*' | sed 's/   File System Personality:   \(.*\)$/\1/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df /path/to/file | sed -n 2p | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

will give you the device the file is on. To combine this directly with `diskutil info` use

```
diskutil info $(df /path/to/file | sed -n 2p | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to determine the device that contains a file is to use `df`. For example:

```
$ df /Users/mj/bin/imgls
Filesystem   1K-blocks      Used Available Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1 488347692 418217076  38565452    92% 3141515 9223372036851634292    0%   /
```

You can use `cut` if you just want the device (I used `tail` as a crude way to remove the `df` header).

```
$ df /Users/mj/bin/imgls | tail -1  | cut -d ' ' -f 1
/dev/disk1s1
```